# performance testing for Java Web Application

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Is there any easy tool from which we can enter 1000s of data into DB. Actually we have to do some performance testing and improvement in our Java Web Application. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: we also want to know which query is taking more time.how to check how much does a query take to execute.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is a java-based web-application load and stress-testing tool than many people use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your particular stack looks like, but if you are using something like Spring/Hibernate, I have used this small builder pattern library to create (and destroy) mounds of test data to run through JUnit integration type tests very easily:

http://code.google.com/p/make-it-easy/

There is also DBUnit http://www.dbunit.org/ which might do what you want, but I have had less success with it in the kinds of apps I have worked on.  It might be just the ticket for your needs, however.